# Rotate complex numbers to maximize sum of abs of real part

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers

In a recent program I met the following challange:

What is the angle $\phi$ complex numbers $a_1 .. a_n$  have to be rotated by to maximize the sum of the *absolute* value of the real parts?

> $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$
>
> $f(\phi)=\sum_\limits{n} \big|\text{Re}( a_ne^{i\phi})\big|$
>
> Maximize f with respect to $\phi$.

Is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious thing is to first solve all

$$Re(a_n \exp(i\phi)) = 0$$

to partition the circle into $2n$ intervals by $\phi_n$ (assuming all the $a_n$ have different arguments),
on each interval the signs $s_n \in \{-1, 1\}$ of $Re(...)$ will be constant. Then

$$f(\phi) = \sum_n |Re(a_n \exp(i\phi))|$$
$$f(\phi) = \sum_n s_n Re(a_n \exp(i\phi))$$
$$f(\phi) = \sum_n Re(s_n a_n \exp(i\phi))$$
$$f(\phi) = Re(\sum_n s_n a_n \exp(i\phi))$$
$$f(\phi) = Re((\sum_n s_n a_n) \exp(i\phi))$$

Maximize these on every such interval of $\phi$, then just compare (for all the combinations of signs).

Alternatively, let $a_n = A_n \exp(-i\theta_n)$, then

$$f(\phi) = \sum_n A_n |Re(\exp(i(\phi-\theta_n)))|$$

$$f(\phi) = \sum_n A_n |(\cos(\phi-\theta_n)|$$

$$f(\phi) = \sum_n A_n
|\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta_n) + \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta_n)|$$

$$f(\phi) = \cos(\phi) \sum_n s_n A_n \cos(\theta_n)
 + \sin(\phi) \sum_n s_n A_n \sin(\theta_n))$$

and apply the same method.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think there is a more elegant solution then a combinatorial, because of $|\cdot|$.